# Can't update a table with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to edit a table on a sheet in my workbook with vba code. I can enter new data with vba code, but not edit does details in the rows with vba.

I have recycled my code from a different userform in the workbook with edits another table which works fine.

below is my code

```vb
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheets("Transactions").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
    
        If Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "A").Value = Me.txt_Trans_ID.Value Then
        
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "F").Value = Me.cbox_Service.Value      'edits the service type
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "H").Value = Me.Txt_Price.Value         'edits the Price
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "J").Value = Me.cbox_Pay_Meth.Value     'edits the Payment method type
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "K").Value = Me.cbox_Pay_Stat.Value     'edits the Payment Status
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "G").Value = Me.DTPicker1               'edits the date
            Sheets("Transactions").Cells(i, "C").Value = Me.Txt_Cust_ID.Value       'edits the Customer ID
               
        End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me address your issue by showing one of workaround for the text box. Suppose you would like to write text box value from Userform in your sheet, here is some solution:

1)Create a Userform name Userform1, and load Userform1 when click

```
Sub load()

UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

2)On the submit button, assign a sub procedure name to it

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
submit
End Sub
```

3)Create the sub procedure as following:

```
Sub submit()

Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

4)When run the load sub, it will show the Userform and allow me to key in text value

[image]

And last, when I click the submit button, the value is updated in the sheet, hope it is helping :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, I can already enter data from a userform via Sales Form & Expense Form. But when I call the data into an 'Edit Sale Form' to edit the data and submit it to overwrite the data in that row, it does not enter the new data. It only seems to be on this table  in the Transactions sheet. My code works for the other tables in the other sheets.

Comment: The `Sub cmd_Submit_Click()` should not be used to write the function where you want to update the data in `Userform` module, instead you should write the sub in `standard module `, and use `Sub cmd_Submit_Click()` to call the standard module, please try and see

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of module type. Your userform has its code in some kind of class module and the worksheet reports its actions to another kind of class module. They aren't really class modules but the point is that are not standard code modules and they don't communicate very well with each other. The rule to observe - very roughly - is to use code in standard code modules to access objects in class modules.

Therefore, to avoid writing to the sheet from your user form, pass the task to a procedure in a standard code module.

```
Private Sub cmd_Submit_Click()
    UpdateTransaction Me
End Sub
```

Observe that the procedure call passes the entire userform as an argument. Therefore the called procedure will have access to all controls in the form. And here is the procedure that will write to the sheet. Paste it to a standard code module.

```
Sub UpdateTransaction(MyForm As UserForm1)

    Dim Fnd         As Range
    Dim Rt          As Long                     ' target row
    
    With Worksheets("Transactions")
        Set Fnd = .Columns(1).Find(MyForm.Txt_Trans_ID.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Rt = Fnd.Row
            .Cells(Rt, "C").Value = MyForm.Txt_Cust_ID.Value       'edits the Customer ID
            .Cells(Rt, "F").Value = MyForm.cbox_Service.Value      'edits the service type
            .Cells(Rt, "H").Value = MyForm.Txt_Price.Value         'edits the Price
            .Cells(Rt, "J").Value = MyForm.cbox_Pay_Meth.Value     'edits the Payment method type
            .Cells(Rt, "K").Value = MyForm.cbox_Pay_Stat.Value     'edits the Payment Status
            .Cells(Rt, "G").Value = MyForm.DTPicker1               'edits the date
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A lot to get my head around there... I'm just new to VBA but I think I can follow your code.  I just cant understand why it is only my Transaction table will not update from my Edit Sale Form.  I am passing the Trans_ID from a listbox on another UserForm

Comment: Each of the sheets in your workbook is an `object` and so are each of your `forms`. From a standard code module you can reach any of the objects in the `VBA Project` but the connection between the objects is limited. Picture it like a hub and satellites. Each of your forms might have *Read/Write* access to the `ActiveSheet` (the tab you last looked at before giving control to the form) but it would be *Read Only* for all others. Documentation on what "works" and what doesn't is sparse. Therefore it's safer not to try at all and empower the hub.